# problems with using IntelliJ, Jersey, glassfish and tomcat. Getting some exception (HTTP Status 500)

Tags: xml, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, jersey

I'm trying to create a Web Service RESTFUL using Jersey with Maven and Tomcat. When I do execute my web service does throw some exceptions and doesn't work. I am using IntelliJ 2021.2.3, and Tomcat 9.0.53
Here is the URL that I am using: http://localhost:8080/TaskMenegerMaven-1.0/rest/test

How could I solve it?

### web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>web</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
     4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.denis</groupId>
    <artifactId>TaskMenegerMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.28</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

### Service

```
package web;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/test")
public class TestService {
    @GET
    public String testServlet(){
        return "Servlet is working :)";
    }
}
```

### Exception

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)

Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:171)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:146)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:885)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:839)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:748)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1175)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1148)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1144)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$RuntimeConfigConfigurator.init(ApplicationHandler.java:181)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:289)
    java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4203)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:258)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:346)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace to your question (edit the question). The real cause of the error is after _"Root Cause"_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix “unsupported class file major version 60” in tomcat9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603262/how-to-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-tomcat9)