# SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

so I'm in a new internship position and I was told to modernize a JEE applciation.
I've migrated the code in my machine in both .rar , .tar.gz and raw source code , and I sotill get the same problem.
so here is the full stack trace of the problem :

```
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/7.0.109
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Apr 22 2021 18:43:38 UTC
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 7.0.109.0
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            5.10.93-1-MANJARO
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           17.0.1+12
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/azseza/JAVA/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/azseza/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/apache-tomcat-7.0.109
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/azseza/JAVA/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/azseza/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/apache-tomcat-7.0.109
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/azseza/JAVA/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 415 ms
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.109
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener] is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:37 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) for context '/registre'
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:37 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/azseza/JAVA/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/registre/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/azseza/JAVA/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/registre/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:37 PM com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ConverterConfigHandler collect
WARNING: @FacesConverter is using both value and forClass, only value will be applied.
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:38 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 6.2
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:38 PM org.primefaces.extensions.application.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 6.0.0
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5653)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Feb 14, 2022 12:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/registre] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 14, 2022 12:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4851 ms
```

The pom.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bd.csrp.registre</groupId>
    <artifactId>registre</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>registre</name>
    <description>***</description>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>

        <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-jpa.version>1.0.1.Final</hibernate-jpa.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>5.0.2.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <jsf-api.version>2.2.8</jsf-api.version>
        <jsf-impl.version>2.2.8</jsf-impl.version>
        <primefaces.version>6.2</primefaces.version>
        <primefaces-extensions.version>6.0.0</primefaces-extensions.version>
        <primefaces.themes.version>1.0.9</primefaces.themes.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4-1200-jdbc4</postgresql.version>
        <dozer.version>5.4.0</dozer.version>
        <java.mail.version>1.4</java.mail.version>
        <velocity.version>1.6.2</velocity.version>
         <ehcache-version>3.6.1</ehcache-version>

        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <commons.beanutils.version>1.7.0</commons.beanutils.version>
        <commons.codec.version>1.3</commons.codec.version>
        <commons.collection.version>3.2</commons.collection.version>
        <commons.digester.version>1.8</commons.digester.version>
        <commons.dcp.version>1.1</commons.dcp.version>
        <commons.pool.version>1.1</commons.pool.version>
        <commons.discovery.version>0.4</commons.discovery.version>
        <commons.logging.version>1.1.1</commons.logging.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.4</commons.io.version>
        <commons.fileupload.version>1.3</commons.fileupload.version>
        <commons.net.version>3.3</commons.net.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <apache.poi.version>3.17</apache.poi.version>
        <itext.version>2.1.7</itext.version>
        <excel.reader.version>1.2</excel.reader.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
        <servlet.api.version>2.5</servlet.api.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>registre</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                        <wtpContextName>${project.build.finalName}</wtpContextName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                        <webresources>
                            <webresource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <targetpath>WEB-INF</targetpath>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </webresource>
                        </webresources>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- XML -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
                <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring process @Configuration classes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>facelets-taglib-jsf20-spring-3</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>



        <!-- Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.beanutils.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.codec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.collection.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.digester.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.pool.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.discovery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.fileupload.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.net.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate & JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${hibernate-jpa.version}</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.dcp.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Java Mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>${java.mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>${velocity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dozer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>${dozer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${ehcache-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <!-- Export Excel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Export PDF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myjeeva.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>excelReader</artifactId>
            <version>${excel.reader.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jasper dependancy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
            <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
            <version>1.5-beta1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>




        <!-- Javax Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf-impl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.themes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces-extensions.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces-extensions.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-codemirror</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces-extensions.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>developpement</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>datapipeline-mvn-repo</id>
            <url>https://raw.github.com/fredtucs/mvnrepository/mvn-repo/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.security.taglibs.facelets</id>
            <url>http://spring-security-facelets-taglib.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

And finaly the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please help me , my  JEE heros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse:Tomcat: Failed to read candidate component class:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700334/eclipsetomcat-failed-to-read-candidate-component-class)

Comment: Basically: don't use Java 17! Start with Java 8 and upgrade all components gradually. My clients have similar stacks and upgrading it to the currently supported versions is a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have changed the JRE of the IDE, as well as the build path system library to Java 8 and the problem persists.
Any idea on how to try a bit harded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring `3.2.0.RELEASE` uses [asm 4.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm/4.0), which does not support Java 8 or higher.

Since Java 7 is not supported any more, you should upgrade Spring to the latest patch release:

```xml
<spring.version>3.2.18.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

This version uses [asm 5.0.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm/5.0.4), which supports Java 8 (but not later versions).

Upgrading in the same minor version is theoretically safe, so you should not experience too many problems.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this proposition and get back to you